# How to make loop with features selection by features importance where deleted features with imp = 0 or below mean imp in each iteration in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, machine-learning, feature-selection

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

**Input data:**

- Y - binnary target
- X1...X5 - predictors

**Source code of DataFrame:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from xgboost import XGBClassifier

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Y"] = [1,0,1,0]
df["X1"] = [111,12,150,270]
df["X2"] = [22,33,44,55]
df["X3"] = [1,1,0,0]
df["X4"] = [0,0,0,1]
df["X5"] = [150, 222,230,500]

Y   | X1  | X2  | X3    | X4    | X5  | ...  | Xn
----|-----|-----|-------|-------|-----|------|-------
1   | 111 | 22  | 1     | 0     | 150 | ...  | ...
0   | 12  | 33  | 1     | 0     | 222 | ...  | ...
1   | 150 | 44  | 0     | 0     | 230 | ...  | ...
0   | 270 | 55  | 0     | 1     | 500 | ...  | ...
```

And I make features selection by deleting features with importance = 0 in each iteration or if the are not features with imporance = 0 I delete features with importance below mean importance in that iteraton:

**First iteration:**

```
model_importance = XGBClassifier()
model_importance.fit(X = df.drop(labels=["Y"], axis=1), y = df["Y"])

importances = pd.DataFrame({"Feature":df.drop(labels=["Y"], axis=1).columns,
                            "Importance":model_importance.feature_importances_})

importances_to_drop_1 = importances[importances["Importance"]==0].index.tolist()

df.drop(columns = importances_to_drop_1, axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

**Second iteration:**

```
model_importance_2 = XGBClassifier()
model_importance_2.fit(X = df.drop(labels=["Y"], axis=1), y = df["Y"])

importances_2 = pd.DataFrame({"Feature":df.drop(labels=["Y"], axis=1).columns,
                            "Importance":model_importance_2.feature_importances_})

importances_to_drop_2 = importances_2[importances_2["Importance"]<importances_2.Importance.mean()].index.tolist()

df.drop(columns = importances_to_drop_2, axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

**Requirements:**

- I need to create loop where in each iteration will be deleted features with importance = 0 or if there are not features with importance = 0 is some iteration delete features with importance below mean importance in that iteration
- At the end I need to have at least 150 features
- I need that in one loop (one segment of code) not like now in a few segments of code

How can I do that in Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a for loop to iterate a set number of times and then use a conditional to drop using method 1 or 2 depending if method one has any importances=0 or not.

```
iterations = 20
for i in range(iterations):
    model_importance = XGBClassifier()
    model_importance.fit(X = df.drop(labels=["Y"], axis=1), y = df["Y"])

    importances = pd.DataFrame({"Feature":df.drop(labels=["Y"], axis=1).columns,
                            "Importance":model_importance.feature_importances_})

    importances_to_drop_1 = importances[importances["Importance"]==0].index.tolist()
    if len(df.columns) - len(importances_to_drop_1) <= 150:
        break

    if len(importances_to_drop_1) > 0:
        df.drop(columns = importances_to_drop_1, axis = 1, inplace = True)
    else:
        importances_to_drop_2 = importances_2[importances_2["Importance"]<importances_2.Importance.mean()].index.tolist()
        
        if len(df.columns) - len(importances_to_drop_2) <= 150:
            break

        df.drop(columns = importances_to_drop_2, axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Jonynul Islam, but using your solution I remove almost all predictors (only one will stay), how can I modify this code so as to have at least for example 150 variables at the end of each iterations ? Or loop have to stop if only 150 variales will stay, can you modify you code please ?

Comment: Do you want to remove only 1 feature per iteration? If multiple features have 0 importances in a given iteration, how do you want to decide which feature to drop?

Comment: we have to remove ALL features with importance = 0 or if there are not features with importance = 0 we have to remove features with importance below mean but Loop has to stop run if after that iteration in df will stay below 150 variables :)

Comment: stop loop if in df is less than 150 variables, it could be clearer Joynul Islam

Comment: In that case, say you have 300 features to start with. In the first iteration we calculate features with importance = 0. What if the number of features with importance=0 is 200. So the code will remove 200 features in the first iteration. So we are down to 100 already which is below your 150 limit. I don't quite understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: in case that you described (we have 300 input features and 200 have importance = 0) lopp has to stop running and DO NOT remove any variables because after remove we will have number of variables below definided point 150 variables :)

Comment: Understood, above post is edited. Does that do what you want?

Comment: I am testing your code on my df, give me a moment, please